# What does <EntityFilter> in Quickbooks XML do?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

No matter what I try for EntityFilter, I can't seem to get any results. I believe that I must be mis-understanding what the EntityFilter does.

What entities is it filtering if I use it in a `<DepositQueryRq>`?

Comment: The entities that made a deposit.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/pasting from the documentation:

`EntityFilter
An entity refers to a person on the QuickBooks Customer list, Vendor list, Employee list, or Other Names list. You can use an EntityQuery request to get information about all the entities that are set up in the QuickBooks file.`

So an `EntityFilter` lets you filter deposits by entity. e.g. You can use it to get all deposits for a specific entity.